# Using modifier on overridden functions in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

Is it possible to use a modifier on a function that was overriden ?

I have a virtual function and overrided it in another class, but I get error when I call it due to using a modifier on it.

```
abstract contract A {
function stake(
        address _userAddress,
        uint256 _amount
    ) internal virtual {}

function investByToken(
        address _userAddress,
        IERC20Upgradeable _token,
        uint256 _amount,
    ) external payable {
// ... calling some functions like deduct fee

stake(_userAddress, _liquidity);
     }
}
```

```
contract B is A {
 function stake(
        address _userAddress,
        uint256 _amount
    ) internal override updateRewards {}
}
```

Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Transaction reverted:
**function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function**", method="estimateGas"

I'm getting this error while testing with hardhat, but it's working fine on Mainnet.

Comment: When you run the same code without the modifier, do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add modifiers to the overriding function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

abstract contract A {
    function stake(address _userAddress, uint256 _amount) internal virtual {}
}


contract B is A {
    modifier updateRewards {
        _;
    }

    function callStake() external {
        stake(address(0x123), 1);
    }
    
    function stake(address _userAddress, uint256 _amount) internal override updateRewards {}
}
```

The "function selector was not recognized" error message is thrown when you're trying to invoke an unreachable or non-existing function. Mind that in your example, the `stake()` function has `internal` visibility which makes it unreachable for external callers (such as your JS app or IDE). See the [docs page](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#function-visibility) for more info on function visibility.

Either change its visibility to `external` or `public` (in both contracts) or wrap it with another `external` / `public` function (see the code of this answer).

Comment: Thank you @Petr Hejda for your answer. I've already called stake from an external method in contract A. But the problem is when I test it on hardhat network (with npx hardhat test) I don't get the same result as what I get on mainnet networks. For example, on BSC network everything works fine but I get "function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function" when I start my tests.

Comment: @AliJalal If you're able to execute the function on the public network, then the contract on the public network has a `stake()` function that has `external` or `public` visibility. Can you share the address of the public contract so I can check it? ... Also note that the selector changes when the input param types change. So for example if the `stake()` function in the public contract contains 3 input params, or 2 params with different types (e.g. `stake(address,uint8)`), then it has a different selector than your function.

Comment: I edited contract A on the post. Please take a look and let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: @AliJalal I see that the updated code can execute the `stake()` function **through** `investByToken()`. Because of the function visibility mentioned earlier, it is possible to invoke `investByToken()` from an external app, but it is not possible to invoke `stake()` from an external app.

Comment: @PetrHejda yes I got your point, but the error is raised when `stake()` is called from `investByToken()`. I think there is a problem on hardhat network because its behaviour is different with Mainnet of Polygon

Comment: @AliJalal Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that I can copy-paste to my project, run it, to and get the same result as you do. My guess is that your code is calling the `investByToken()` on a contract that doesn't implement this function, or that it's calling the `stake()` function directly (which is not reachable). Or possibly there might be  another issue calling another non-existent function that is not related to this part of the code that you shared.

Comment: @PetrHejda Ok. I'll do it.